# "cannot resolve tag svg" with html5 in Visual studio 2012

Tags: html, svg, visual-studio-2012

I following the jump start course on Microsoft virtual acadamy. In module 3 they do some fun stuf with SVG. when I try to do the same in visual studio 2012 the  tag can not be found

this is de html for the default page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>WindowsSandbox</title>

    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>

    <!-- WindowsSandbox references -->
    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/js/default.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <menu id="optoinsMenu">
        <li id="optionsMenuText">Title</li>
        <svg></svg>
    </menu>
    <section style="margin-left: 120px; margin-top: 45px">

        <hgroup>
            <h1>Markup</h1>
            <h2>Demo</h2>
        </hgroup>
        <p>Favorites:</p>
        <form onsubmit="mrRock.play(); return false;">
            <input id="favUrl" type="url" required="required" placeholder="http://www.naam.com" />
            <input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save" />
        </form>
        <audio src="/audio/01 - MacDonald, Amy - Mr Rock & Roll.mp3" id="mrRock"></audio>
        <video src="Video/Exam480Mod6Part2_high.mp4" controls="controls" />
    </section>
</body>
```

It is a standard javascript windows store project.
Am I missing a refernce?

Michiel

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could it be you are using ReSharper?

Comment: This seems still to be a problem in ReSharper 8 though, I'm facing the same problem!

Comment: I've surprised somebody can accept "resharper uninstallation" as a solution.

Comment: Still a problem in ReSharper 8.2. To temporarily suspend ReSharper while editing svg tags: Tools -> Options -> ReSharper -> General and click "Suspend".

Comment: It seems to be [an assigned bug there](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-386020).

Comment: PS. still a problem in Resharper Ultimate 2016.2 & VS2015 upt 3

Comment: If you click on the squiggly line you can use the tool icon in the left margin to reduce the severity of the inspection to "do not show", which effectively turns this warning off. Not perfect but stops the sqigglies until it gets fixed properly.